# SupportsPinning is not working

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on outlook web addin. App is working fine except pinning option. I have added support pinning in manifest.xml file. but it is not showing pinning option in view.

Please check the manifest xml file here : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/df5063058d7b1a4e6e35d80f4b253544

i followed the steps mentioned here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Outlook are you running, and on what platform? According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane), support for pinnable taskpanes is currently limited to only specific versions of Outlook on Windows:

```
**Note**: Pinnable taskpanes are currently only supported by Outlook 2016 for Windows (build 7668.2000 or later for users in the Current or Office Insider Channels, build 7900.xxxx or later for users in Deferred channels).
```

If your version of Outlook / platform *should* support pinnable task panes (according to the documentation), but it's not working for you, I'd suggest that you review the [outlook-add-in-command-demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo) repo on GitHub (which implements a pinnable task pane) to determine how your implementation differs from that one.

Comment: Pinning doesn't seem to work in Office 365 / Outlook for Business Version 2110 (Build 14527.20234)